# Two Azure web apps sending emails at very different speeds

Tags: azure

I have deployed two Azure web apps containing web jobs that perform sending of emails.  It's the same code deployed with minor web.config changes and pointing to different dbs with the same structure.  They use the same SMTP channel (smtp.office365.com, port 587), and server A is on a higher spec and takes 6 seconds to send an email, and server B is on a lower spec and sends an email in under a second.  Both are located in South Africa North.  The performance measurement is strictly around the sending of the email, so it can't be a db issue.

Both servers are operating well and I can't see any obvious performance issues.  The times taken to send emails are consistently around the same speed throughout the day.

Where should I look to resolve this difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow troubleshooting steps to understand the web apps slow performance:

- Yes, it may not be a db issue.
- Recheck those minor `web.config` changes that is pointed to different dbs.
- [Troubleshoot](https://www.znetlive.com/kb/5432A/managed-services/managed-azure/how-to-troubleshoot-slow-web-app-performance-issues-in-azure-app-service.html) for less performance on the web apps.
- Like some of the steps are Service Health checks, [Monitor Azure WebJobs](https://stackify.com/monitor-azure-webjobs-performance/), Metrics.
- Any program code or database queries are in-efficient.
- You can enable application diagnostics and use the Application Insights Profiler.
- Use AutoHeal, as it recycles the WP (worker process) on configuration modifications and to execute the request on the given time. And you can restart the web app from portal, if you need this by automatically then you can make use of this AutoHeal.
- To automate this on your web app you need to add `triggers` in the `web.config` file in the root.

Hope there is no link between sending emails with the help of database, means you are not getting the data from db then sending the emails.